# How to create a blocking thread-safe Stream in Java?

Tags: java, thread-safety, java-stream

I want to create a `java.util.stream.Stream` that blocks on [terminal actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) and uses an arbitrary object for synchronization. The Stream's methods must do so themselves in a transparent way such that I could safely pass the Stream to code that is not aware of the synchronization.

Consider the following example:

```
void libraryMethod(Stream<Whatever> s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) { /* ... */ }
    s.filter(Library::foo).forEach(Library::bar);
}

/* Elsewhere in my code */

Set<Whatever> aSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(...);
/* ... */
libraryMethod(new MyBlockingStream<>(set.stream(), set));
```

Before performing `forEach`, I want `aSet`'s lock to be acquired *by the MyBlockingStream itself* and released only when `forEach` terminates. This should guarantee that I don't get `ConcurrentModificationException`s because other threads might want to modify the set. I can't use `synchronized (aSet)` on the entire `libraryMethod` because that would block `aSet` for much longer then needed.

Is it possible to do this? If so, are there any existing implementations that do that or do I have to write it myself?

Note: this question has nothing to do with how the Stream performs the actions - I don't care whether it's parallel or not. I am aware that there exist intrinsically unsynchronizable `iterator()` and `spliterator()` methods. I don't care about them either.

Comment: What exactly is the use case? You want to have multiple instances of `MyBlockingStream` in different threads and only one instance is allowed to `forEach` at a time?

Comment: Exactly. This is just like what `Collections.synchronizedCollection()` does, for example. The use case is: the streamed object is a container that may be accessed from many threads but no parallelism is needed; this is just a safety measure.

Comment: As I understand `Collections.synchronizedCollection()` does something different. There you want to use the same collection in all threads and make access to it thread safe.

Comment: From `Collections` source (Collections.SynchronizedCollection.stream()): `return c.stream(); // Must be manually synched by user!` I'm basically trying to make it synch itself. As I said, the Streams I'm looking for would be returned in a `stream()` method of a custom container that must be thread-safe. I thought that messing with streams was a better solution than only using `stream()` in `synchronized` blocks.
In the meanwhile, I hacked together a SynchronizedStream<T> and Int/Long/Double variants. If nothing better turns up I'll upload them to Github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing: https://gist.github.com/OLEGSHA/bda28ffaa4b24e64b94a8c30c3ad9b0c. These Stream wrappers `synchronize` all terminal operations using a provided object and wrap streams from intermediate operations.

This is essentially

```
public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    synchronized (monitor) {
        parent.forEach(action);
    }
}
```

for every terminal operation in `Stream` interface. `IntStream`, `LongStream` and `DoubleStream` versions included.

I think there must be a better solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lock.

```
public class Example {
    public static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    private static void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Runnable createRunnable() {
        return () -> {
            try {
                Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").stream().forEach(e -> {
                    if (!lock.isHeldByCurrentThread())
                        lock.lock();

                    sleep();
                    System.out.println(String.format("thread %s with element %s", Thread.currentThread().getId(), e));
                });
            } finally {
                if(lock.isHeldByCurrentThread())
                    lock.unlock();
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(createRunnable());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(createRunnable());
        Thread t3 = new Thread(createRunnable());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        System.out.println("join all threads");
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }
}
```

The thread first to reach `forEach` will lock up all other threads.

Output in this case is

```
join all threads
thread 16 with element a
thread 16 with element b
thread 16 with element c
thread 15 with element a
thread 15 with element b
thread 15 with element c
thread 14 with element a
thread 14 with element b
thread 14 with element c
```

### EDIT 1

As @Holger pointed out this will not work if the stream get nested. The inner stream will release the lock too early.

Comment: Pfft... This is not what I meant. I presented a better example and clarified the question in general. Thank you for the effort anyway!

Comment: What if the stream is empty? Then, you’re trying to release a lock you never held.

Comment: But you’re also doing wrong when the lock is already held before the method is entered. In the end, what do you gain by this asymmetry? You’re still managing the lock outside the stream operation (unlocking in a `finally`), so why not cleanly lock at the beginning of the `try` block…

Comment: @Holger The question was to only lock inside `forEach` so that the operations before `forEach` are not blocked. I can not follow your last remark on assymetrie. I lock once and I unlock once. If the lock is held by someone else before it will wait. That is what the example shows. First only thread 16 will execute the `forEach`despite all threads running in parallel.

Comment: I didn’t say “someone else”; if the thread already owns the lock before entering the method, this code will release it, without having locked it. The question was to lock inside `forEach`, but of course, also to unlock inside the stream operation, as there is no advantage, when the caller still needs to unlock externally, that just adds a pile of error sources.